# BigQuery query execution from GWT taking very long time

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using BigQuery with our GWT application and Google APP engine. 
The query execution ,( from the application) is taking very long time like 4 to 5 seconds.
There are no more than 200 rows in table. This latency is effecting the whole performance of the application.

The query consists of where and groupby  clauses.

Is there any way that the bigquery execution can be optimized to improve the performance.

thank in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what query you ran? Perhaps a job id of a query that was slower than you expected?

Comment: How fast do you expect them to be? The good thing about BigQuery is that it only takes seconds to analyze arbitrary amounts of data. But then, if you only have small datasets, it will still take seconds to analyze them.

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery is not designed for tables with 200 rows. It will always take several seconds to get the answer. BigQuery is an asset when you want to analyze billions of rows.

Under this size, you'll be better off using more traditional data storage solutions such as Cloud SQL or the App Engine Datastore.

If you want to keep SQL capability, Cloud SQL is the best guess.