# Increment speed on query data to Bigquery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm developing an application to execute many queries into bigquery using Jobs.Query class. This is my piece of code:

```
    public JObject getData(BigqueryService service, String query)
    {
        JObject result = new JObject();
        JobsResource j = service.Jobs;
        QueryRequest qr = new QueryRequest();
        qr.Query = query;

        QueryResponse response =  j.Query(qr, projectId).Execute();
        if ((bool)response.JobComplete)
        {
            return getResults(response.Schema, response.Rows);
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
            while (true) {
                GetQueryResultsResponse response2 = service.Jobs.GetQueryResults(projectId, response.JobReference.JobId).Execute();
                if ((bool)response2.JobComplete)
                {
                    return getResults(response2.Schema, response2.Rows);
                }
                DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;
                TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan(end.Ticks - start.Ticks);
                if (total.Minutes > 0 || total.Seconds > 50) return getResults(null, null);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
    }
```

My problem is that the query execution is very slow for the size of data. Are there any way to increase speed of the query?

I'm talking about a table that contain more than 20 milion rows.

Today, I've done a list with querys timestamps. Each timestamp is the time of execution the 4 querys.

-00:00:06.2929905
-00:00:06.8925675
-00:00:05.0319329
-00:00:05.6336228
-00:00:07.2206028
-00:00:05.2911213
-00:00:05.0546701
-00:00:04.3276083
-00:00:05.7575818
-00:00:04.1528799
-00:00:05.2664854
-00:00:05.0738185
-00:00:05.5472279
-00:00:05.1223429
-00:00:04.7509914
-00:00:04.9643928
-00:00:04.5182521
-00:00:04.6950590
-00:00:06.0061839
-00:00:06.7736054
-00:00:06.3931505
-00:00:06.0068689
-00:00:07.2904883
-00:00:04.3762012
-00:00:09.7467363
-00:00:12.9430536
-00:00:11.4525429
-00:00:13.4580112
-00:00:07.2501061
-00:00:11.9368635
-00:00:20.0649572
-00:00:22.8073734
-00:00:33.5651125
-00:00:20.3412234
-00:00:41.2743429
-00:00:46.3231917
-00:01:03.8191158
-00:00:33.4181420
-00:00:42.9427840
-00:00:26.3853840
-00:00:19.3615288
-00:00:20.6219836
-00:00:23.1905747

Is it possible that when more queries executed, BigQuery will run more slower?

Thanks

**22/08/2014 EDIT:** After several days,I noticed that depending the time of day, the queries run more slower o more faster. Is possible that these queries run slowly because the source table is filled through InsertAll() (streaming data) ?

There are any way to run this queries more faster? (4-10 seconds always)

Comment: possible duplicate of [BigQuery query execution from GWT taking very long time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953929/bigquery-query-execution-from-gwt-taking-very-long-time)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455494/bigquery-performance-is-this-correct

Comment: I'm talking about a table that contain more than 20 milion rows

Comment: With a jobID it may be possible to get a better sense of the query execution, but regardless of that you're going to run into issues as your polling loop doesn't appear to have any exponential backoff (which means you could get API errors from polling too quickly)

Comment: Well, I've done two important changes in my code. Now, I execute each query in different thread and I put sleep thread 1 second in polling loop. So, I explain more especific at top

Comment: More information at the top